# using polenta to make hamburger

Tags: vegan, polenta

Hello I am cooking vegan today and I want to know, if I can use **polenta** to make some kind of food, that is similar to hamburger meat.

( I want to use polenta, because I already bought it and try to find a use for it. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're going to get a good ground beef substitute from polenta, for that I would recommend TVP or other vegan soy crumbles, seitan or even mushrooms. However, if you're interested in making a veggie burger out of polenta, I'm sure you could look online for a recipe (for example [here](http://www.mealsmatter.org/recipes-meals/recipe/45804), but you may find others). It's certainly not going to taste anything remotely like beef, though.

Comment: There are a whole bunch of recipes for veggie burgers using soy crumbles, TVP or seitan. Your polenta would make a delicious side dish, or I've seen recipes for polenta "fries." Just do a google search. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. yup, I think i am gonna find a good use for the polenta, as a side dish.